# bazel fetch //... does nothing for BUILD and WORKSPACE files

Tags: dependencies, bazel, external-dependencies

I can't get bazel to download and build external dependencies.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here,
but let's take `gtest` as an example.
At the root of my workspace I have a `gtest.BUILD` and `WORKSPACE`.

They are defined as:

**gtest.BUILD:**

```
cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/*.cc"],
        exclude = ["src/gtest-all.cc"]
    ),
    hdrs = glob([
        "include/**/*.h",
        "src/*.h"
    ]),
    copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

**WORKSPACE:**

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "gtest",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.7.0.zip",
    build_file = "gtest.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.7.0",
)
```

I try to use `gtest` in my other code, but the external dependency does not exist.
When I run `bazel fetch //...` it does nothing.

I'm trying to follow bazel's documentation on [external dependencies](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html),
and I can't figure out what I'm leaving out.  Any thoughts?

I looked inside `$(bazel info output_base)/external`,
but I don't see any of m built dependencies there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that nothing in your current workspace `//...` depends on any target in `@gtest//...`, so running `bazel fetch //...` doesn't tell Bazel that it needs to download `@gtest`.

```
$ bazel fetch //...
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
...........
$
```

If you try to run `bazel fetch @gtest//...` directly, it'll download the archive as expected:

```
$ bazel fetch @gtest//...
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.7.0.zip) = b58cb7547a28b2c718d1e38aee18a3659c9e3ff52440297e965f5edffe34b6d0
Building: no action
```

Now, if you add a target that depends on `@gtest//:main` and run `bazel fetch //...` again, it'll download `@gtest`:

```
$ bazel clean --expunge
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.

$ cat BUILD
filegroup(
    name = "gtest",
    srcs = ["@gtest//:main"],
)

$ bazel fetch //...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
..........
INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.7.0.zip) = b58cb7547a28b2c718d1e38aee18a3659c9e3ff52440297e965f5edffe34b6d0
Building: no action

$ ls $(bazel info output_base)/external
bazel_tools  @bazel_tools.marker  gtest  @gtest.marker  local_config_cc  @local_config_cc.marker
```

Comment: ah, thanks.  I assumed `bazel fetch //...` got all of the dependencies despite whether they were being used.

Comment: You can use "Bazel sync" for that.